# Choppy / Unusable Install after download? Also doesn't accept password?

Tags: server, password, performance, desktop-environments, lts

I installed 18.04 Server first, and it never accepted the password I created (even after going into the command line to change it).

So I downloaded the ISO for 18.04 Desktop and installed it without issues (no lag, no choppiness).

Once I boot into Ubuntu after the install is complete, two things happen:

1) It is extremely choppy. The mouse literally moves once every 2-3 seconds

2) It does not accept the password I know is correct (since it was giving me problems, I made it extremely simple for test purposes)

The machine is dual Xeon X5650's with 72GB of RAM. I've experienced no other issues.

What can I possibly do to get this up and running?

Thanks.

Comment: You started by mentioning server (which has no gui & thus I'm suspicious it's a server you're installing on, esp. with dual xeon's..).   Then moved to desktop install mentioning only dual xeons & ram.  The hardware requirements for Server & Desktop are very different - Server has no requirements as to gpu, desktop does (which many servers cannot meet) - did you check?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements   If you don't have a required 3d-gpu-memory etc - a lighter DEsktops also mentioned in url may be suitable)